# Flutter - GridView/ListView.builder with row with containers taking same height of large container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to design a vertical scrollable view of the following and I currently I am using GridView with childAspectRation of 0.7 to do this but this won't work as some text can takes up more height (text to be hidden) or lesser height (too much whitespace) . However, I want each of the Individual Grid View to take the highest of the largest GridView. E.g. Title A = 100 height dynamically calculated and the rest are less than 100 height then all the Grid View should take height 100.

I also know that there is a combination of Column and Row with Intrinsic Height but I am not able to get it done as the Intrinsic Height is based on each row instead of all the row.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using Wrap? then inside the wrap is your card that base on the text which how long or short also you can make it more flexible on that way.

Comment: @ArbiterChil can you advise how this can be done? I tried playing with it but I am not very familiar with this and not able to achieve what I need

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of it.

```
final listofYourModel = [
     YouModeldata(
      title:"title",
      description: "Longtexttttttttttt"),
      YouModeldata(
      title:"title",
      description: "Longtexttttttttttt"),
     ];

     Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child:  Wrap(
         alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
         spacing: 10,
         runSpacing: 10
         children: listofYourModel.map((e)
         //Your Card Widget
         YourCardWidget(
          title: e.title,
          description: e.description
          ),
         ).toList()
        ),
       )
```

if this cant be scroll wrap this one to SingleSchildScrollview

Comment: @Tan Boon Jun i updated my answer